# Display shipping method for special customer group only

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, customer-group

I want to display certain shipping methods - like "collection by customer" for special customer groups only. 
All I found is the Amasty "Shipping & Payment By Customer Groups" extension. Is there a free way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below code and if it works for you then you can modify and make it better for fulfilling your requirement.

Code hides free-shipping method for wholesale customer group.

Overwritten class `Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping`

```
class Anshu_ShippingFilter_Model_Shipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping {

    public function collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request) {
        if (!$this->_checkCarrierAvailability($carrierCode, $request)) {
            return $this;
        }
        return parent::collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
    }

    protected function _checkCarrierAvailability($carrierCode, $request = null) {
        $isLoggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
        if ($isLoggedIn) {

            $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
            if (2 == $groupId && 'freeshipping' == $carrierCode) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use for `Magento 2` like above code with some changes for customer group ?

Comment: @PayalPatel Didn't check in Magento 2, so not sure, how it will work or behave.

Comment: @PayalPatel For magento2 how to possible to hide free shipping method for specific customer group you have any idea reply me